# How to set Localization in Stimulsoft Js 2015 Viewer?

Tags: javascript, c#, stimulsoft

I ame using StimulSoft Js 2015 viewer to show my report, that designed by StimuSolft Report Tools. and I need set localization for Js viewer To make the StiMvcViewer component "speak" another language

Answer (score 0):

You should use next method:

```
Stimulsoft.Base.Localization.StiLocalization.setLocalizationFile("Localizations/es.xml");
```

You could find additional information in [Stimusoft Knowlesgebase](http://support.stimulsoft.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/347/35/localization-of-gui-in-reportsjs).

Comment: Thanks but above method has run time error `Stimulsoft.Base.Localization.StiLocalization.setLocalizationFile is not a function`

Comment: Try the latest buils that is available on Stimulsft site.